# Simple 3D trapzoidal rule gone wrong

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to implement a 3D trapezoidal rule function, but I get wrong result and I do not understand what's wrong. Here is the code:

```
Int[xi_, yi_, zi_, xf_, yf_, zf_] := 
 Module[{gridr, gridth, gridph, int1, int2, int3, int4, int5, int6, 
   int7, int8, Int, dx = 0.2, dy = 0.2, dz = 0.2},
  gridr = Range[xi, xf, dx];
  gridth = Range[yi, yf, dy];
  gridph = Range[zi, zf, dz];
  int1 = f[xi, yi, zi] + f[xi, yi, zf] + f[xi, yf, zi] + 
    f[xi, yf, zf] + f[xf, yi, zi] + f[xf, yi, zf] + f[xf, yf, zi] + 
    f[xf, yf, zf];
  int2 = Apply[Plus, 
    Apply[Plus, f[xi, yi, #]] + Apply[Plus, f[xi, yf, #]] + 
       Apply[Plus, f[xf, yi, #]] + Apply[Plus, f[xf, yf, #]] & /@ 
     Rest[gridph]];
  int3 = Apply[Plus, 
    Apply[Plus, f[xi, #, zi]] + Apply[Plus, f[xi, #, zf]] + 
       Apply[Plus, f[xf, #, zi]] + Apply[Plus, f[xf, #, zf]] & /@ 
     Rest[gridth]];
  int4 = Apply[Plus, 
    Apply[Plus, f[#, yi, zi]] + Apply[Plus, f[#, yf, zi]] + 
       Apply[Plus, f[#, yi, zf]] + Apply[Plus, f[#, yf, zf]] & /@ 
     Rest[gridr]];
  int5 = Plus @@ 
     Flatten@Outer[f[xi, #1, #2] &, Rest[gridth], Rest[gridph]] + 
    Plus @@ Flatten@Outer[f[xf, #1, #2] &, Rest[gridth], Rest[gridph]];
  int6 = Plus @@ 
     Flatten@Outer[f[#1, yi, #2] &, Rest[gridr], Rest[gridph]] + 
    Plus @@ Flatten@
      Outer[f[#1, yf, #2] &, Rest[gridr], Rest[gridph]];
  int7 = Plus @@ 
     Flatten@Outer[f[#1, #2, zi] &, Rest[gridr], Rest[gridth]] + 
    Plus @@ Flatten@
      Outer[f[#1, #2, zf] &, Rest[gridr], Rest[gridth]];
  int8 = Plus @@ 
    Flatten@Outer[f[#1, #2, #3] &, Rest[gridr], Rest[gridth], 
      Rest[gridph]];
  Int = int1 + 2 (int2 + int3 + int4) + 4 (int5 + int6 + int7) + 
    8 int8;
  (dx dy dz )/8 Int]
```

The function `f` is given by:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x y z;
```

So the integral should be zero, but I get `4.096`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The function is taken from here: http://utkstair.org/clausius/docs/che505/pdf/IE_eval_N-Dints.pdf page 4

Comment: You have not stated which integral you are trying to compute.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I am trying to integrate the function `f` at the end of the post. The integral should give the same result of `Integrate[f[x,y,z],{x,-8,8},{y,-8,8},{z,-8,8}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what you are doing wrong, but the fact that you can hardly read it yourself should ring a bell: The more code you have, the more can go wrong.

Here is a shorter and more idiomatic implementation (hopefully correct).

```
ClearAll[Int];
Int[f, {xi_, xf_, xn_}, {yi_, yf_, yn_}, {zi_, zf_, zn_}] := 
  Module[{x, y, z, xw, yw, zw},
   x  = Subdivide[N[xi], N[xf], xn];
   y  = Subdivide[N[yi], N[yf], yn];
   z  = Subdivide[N[zi], N[zf], zn];
   xw = Normal[SparseArray[{{1} -> 0.5, {xn + 1} -> 0.5}, {xn + 1}, 1.]];
   yw = Normal[SparseArray[{{1} -> 0.5, {yn + 1} -> 0.5}, {yn + 1}, 1.]];
   zw = Normal[SparseArray[{{1} -> 0.5, {zn + 1} -> 0.5}, {zn + 1}, 1.]];
   
   (N[xf] - N[xi]) (N[yf] - N[yi]) (N[zf] - N[zi]) / N[xn yn zn] Dot[Outer[f, x, y, z], zw, yw, xw]
   ];

Int[f, {-8, 8, 90}, {-8, 8, 90}, {-8, 8, 90}]
```

> 2.45397*10^-11